# usage of js calendar in multiple tabs

Tags: php, javascript, tabs

I am a beginner in php programming and I have the following problem:
I want to use a jsdatepick-calendar in three javascript tabs so i make three objects from this calendar in the same function with different id according to the target id, but unfortunately two of them works well and the third does not.

please advice.

Comment: Since you probably open only one tab at a time, you may try to use only one calendar, that you move from tab to tab.

Comment: How is the third not working well?

Answer (score 0):

Given the JS tabbed menu CSS you can get it to work correctly by modifying the calendar's CSS selectors so that they only work on a specific `UL` id/ Or you can modify the selectors to make the CSS tabs work only on certain ids.

removing `.tabbed-area div div { background: white; padding: 20px; min-height: 250px; position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 0; width: 100%; }` (try it here http://jsfiddle.net/f88gr/2/ ) from the tabbed CSS get it to display correctly.  Now all you need is to assign the date calendar popup a unique id and change the selectors to make it display normally.